# How do I change security context on a directory in CentOS with SELinux?

Tags: centos, selinux

I tried to change it, but it wouldn't let me.

```
# ls -dZ /usr/local/spamassassin
drwx------. spam spam system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       /usr/local/spamassassin

# chcon -v --type=spamd_t /usr/local/spamassassin
changing security context of `/usr/local/spamassassin'
chcon: failed to change context of `/usr/local/spamassassin' to `system_u:object_r:spamd_t:s0': Permission denied
```

`audit.log`

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1483587389.449:354941): avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=31588 comm="spamd" name="spamfilter.log" dev=xvde ino=24109 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:spamd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=file
```

CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you received permission denied is that the spamd_t type is not a valid SELiunx type. You may need some packages to be installed to make it a valid type. I'm not sure there. But I'll go over your answer to ensure you're following best practices.

---

```
semanage fcontext -a -t spamc_home_t "/usr/local/spamassassin(/.*)?"
```

This will add a rule to recursively change the SELinux type to `spamc_home_t` for anything under `/usr/local/spamassassin` including the directory itself but these changes will not take effect immediately.

To make these changes take effect immediately I would run the following immediately after the above command:

```
restorecon -rv /usr/local/spamassassin
```

This will restore the default SELinux contexts based on the rules the system has. Effectively the same behavior that happens when the system is rebooted or a new file is created. It's better than using `chcon` because it reads from the rule set (that you just modified with the above command) rather than making an ad-hoc non-persistent change.

Answer (score 1):

```
# chcon -vR --type=spamc_home_t /usr/local/spamassassin
changing security context of `/usr/local/spamassassin/.bash_profile'
changing security context of `/usr/local/spamassassin/.bash_logout'
changing security context of `/usr/local/spamassassin/.bashrc'
changing security context of `/usr/local/spamassassin/spamfilter.log'
changing security context of `/usr/local/spamassassin'


# semanage fcontext -a -t spamc_home_t "/usr/local/spamassassin(/.*)?"


# service spamassassin restart
Stopping spamd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting spamd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199

I used

```
# grep spamd_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow
```

which spit out a bunch of contexts in a comment and I just had to guess at which one. I don't know how to pick the correct one.